# How to receive details of file on ftp server using spring-integration?

Tags: ftp, spring-integration

I've been searching for answer but I didn't find any. How can I receive information about, for example date of creation file stored on ftp server using spring-integration? Is any chance to do this using inbound-channel-adapter or something like that? 
Thanks for advance.

@EDIT:

Configuration:

```
<int:splitter id="splitter" input-channel="toSplitter" output-channel="ftpChannel"/>

<int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayLS"
                        session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                        request-channel="inbound"
                        command="ls"
                        expression="payload"
                        reply-channel="toSplitter"/>
<int:channel id="toSplitter">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
<bean id="ftpClientFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
    <property name="clientMode" value="0"/>
    <property name="fileType" value="2"/>
    <property name="bufferSize" value="10000000"/>                  
</bean>

<int:channel id="ftpChannel"/>
```

@EDIT:
Problem is solved thanks to Gary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`ls` command of the outbound gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway).

As stated there: "The message payload resulting from an ls operation is a list of file names, or a list of FileInfo objects. These objects provide information such as modified time, permissions etc."

Also, see the [FTP Sample App](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ftp).

Comment: Thank you for response. I'm not quite sure if I understand this gateway. If I want to, for example print result of ls command I should define reply-channel and receive those informations from it?

Comment: The payload will be a list of [FtpFileInfo](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/integration/ftp/session/FtpFileInfo.html) objects containing the properties of each file. If you turn on DEBUG logging, or simply send the payload to a logging channel adapter, or stdout adapter, you will see the file info for each file in the log (consume from the `reply-channel`).

Comment: Ok, I think that I get it, but I'm facing some strange error now. I've tried your sample and when I call `List<Boolean> rmResults = toFtpFlow.lsGetAndRmFiles("/");` I'm getting this error: Unsupported payload type. The only supported payloads are java.io.File, java.lang.String, and byte[] (but listing files works) Do you have any idea what can cause it?

Comment: Bear in mind that sample uses LS, GET and RM - are you sure you want to do that for `/` ? I pointed you to the sample for an example of how to use LS. It's not clear what you mean by "the listing works" but you are getting an error - it sounds like you are sending something invalid to a gateway (using a PUT command). Can you show your configuration?

Comment: But you don't show what's subscribed to `ftpChannel`. Please show all your configuration and a stack trace of the error. Also turn on DEBUG logging and all should become clear to you.

Comment: Well I get rid of that error but I'm doin something wrong for sure. If I understand right splitter forwards informations received from gateway to output-channel, right? So shouldn't output channel be PollableChannel? And If yes (or no) how can I get those informations using java code? Is any way to do that or I have to use some endpoints using xml?